# How to destroy the Object of a SessionScoped bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

Im using a `SessionScoped` object to save the current user of a website. I want to know how i could destroy this object at time of navigation when clicking on a button for example.

Note that im using `CDI` for the injection, and im injecting a simple bean object `User` that contains the name and login of the user.

Comment: One of the major benefits of using container managed objects, such as those which are provided in the Java EE environment, is that the lifecycles of those objects are managed for you.  If you find that your design requires you to manually destroy container managed objects, then that could be a sign that you ought to rethink your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lifespan of a [`SessionScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) bean depends on the HTTP session. If the HTTP session is destroyed (timeout or manually session invalidation), the [`SessionScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) bean will be destroyed too.

From the [`SessionScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) documentation:

> The session context is shared between all servlet requests that occur
>   in the same HTTP session. The session context is destroyed when the
>   HTTP session times out, after all `HttpSessionListeners` have been
>   called, and at the very end of any request in which `invalidate()` was
>   called, after all filters and `ServletRequestListeners` have been
>   called.

---

If you are using JSF, try:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
```

It will invalidate the HTTP session and, consequently, destroy the beans associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Thanks "FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();" saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to destroy your object without the need to invalidated the Session (because the only button, that should do session invalidation is logout) you can use another scope, that is called conversation scope, and could be closed manually.
You can found more info here https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#_the_conversation_scope